# JavaScript - No output

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any of you have a look on my code, because I am not sure why it isn't working.

My current situation is that when you tick the radio button, it will show you an output. For example"You selected Table A".

Unfortunately for my case,it just did nothing when I clicked the radio button.

I'm thinking maybe the displacement of my JavaScript function. But I don't see anything wrong there.

```
<!DOC HTML>
<html>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-  
    1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            $('.frame-wrapper').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).fadeIn();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .frame-wrapper {
            display: none;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-right: 1%;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Please select an option</b>
    A <input type="radio" name="Option" />
    B <input type="radio" name="Option" />
    C <input type="radio" name="Option" />

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div id="tblA" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected A, table tblA is shown

        <frame src="http://www.huawei.com" />
    </div>

    <div id="tblB" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected B, table tblB is shown

        <frame src="https://www.google.com/" />
    </div>

    <div id="tblC" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected C, table tblC is shown
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I already find very strange is that you are loading three different jQuery versions. You are trying to find the `input` element before it exists. Please read the jQuery tutorial to learn the basics first: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/, http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code within:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

Also, you are using more than one `jQuery` source file, you should use only one. Read more about [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs before the DOM has been applied. Move script tags to bottom or wrap in onload function. Test this by console.log'ing the results from your initial selector.

console.log($('input[type="radio"]'));

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thks alot guys..Have a nice Sunday!